# Read Data, Hold Data for N Seconds, Write Data (Kafka, Flink)

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink

Application Reads from a kafka topic.
Each message must be unique (Duplicates Ignored)
holds the data for 'N' Seconds
and writes to different kafka topic as individual messages

Is there a way to hold the message for 'N seconds' and write to kafka
Each message must be written to the same topic after 'N' Seconds from the time it came in.

Currently I'm holding the data in a json structure in memory and every time a message comes in, I loop through all the messages that I have and compare times.

Naturally this is not the way to do it

```
val some_consumer= new FlinkKafkaConsumer09(data_topic
      , new JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema(false), properties)
    some_consumer.setStartFromLatest()
```

```
    val in_stream = env.addSource(some_consumer)
      .filter(!_.isNull)
      .map(x => processMessage(x))
```

```
def process(x: ObjectNode){
 // store message in json if not existing
 // loop through entire set and compare times
 // if after 'N' seconds
   // write to kafka
    kafka_producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](output_topic, the_unique_message))


}
```

Comment: Even if not recommended, what happens if you add `Thread.sleep()` before the `.send()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should hold the messages in Flink state, so that they are checkpointed, and will be restored in the case of failures.

To de-duplicate the stream, you can key the stream by whatever attribute makes an event unique, i.e., `keyBy(x -> x.uniqueId)`. Then I would use a `KeyedProcessFunction`, and buffer the first event for each key in a `ValueState<Event>`. You can use either an EventTimeTimer or a ProcessingTimeTimer to trigger sending out the event (whichever is appropriate). If the scope of de-duplication is N seconds, then you can clear the state at the same time you emit the event.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you

Comment: Won't Flink overwrite the state if there are multiple incoming events before the old event could be sent out?

Comment: The goal here is to only send out the first event for each key, and ignore all subsequent events with that key. So that's not a concern.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Tumbling Windows`
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#tumbling-windows

```java
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
```

The above example means the data goes out each 5 seconds, and you can see it clearly when printing to the console

in your case you don't need `EventTime` and can use `ProcessingTime`. 
Also you don't need keyBy(), just use AllWindow, although it's not a bad idea to use keyBy() so you obtain parallelisms

after `window()`, you can call `FlinkKafkaSink`. Because this window would periodically emit events each X minutes/seconds as you wish

You might be careful about the memory limit, because the data which is kept in the window is stored in memory

Comment: This won't have the desired effect -- a message arriving one millisecond before the end of the window will be sent out right away. (Also, window state doesn't have to be kept in memory, it could be in RocksDB.)

Comment: true, it would then have to use TumblingProcessingTimeWindows

Comment: TumblingProcessingTimeWindows won't work either. The objective is to hold events for N seconds before releasing them, and that's not how time windows work in Flink. Time windows are aligned to the epoch, not to the events.

Comment: events are hold for n seconds in window, and then triggered by the defined time/counts(TimeTrigger or CountTrigger). The default trigger is used when using a specific trigger `.window()`, or? for sure calling .trigger() can use a customized Trigger

Comment: Getting the desired semantics with the window API would require a custom Trigger and an Evictor. At that point using the WIndow API becomes more complex than it's worth.